# TradingView Lightweight Chart price seems to not scale correctly

Tags: javascript, charts, tradingview-api, lightweight-charts

I just added the real time data of bitcoin to my chart. There has been a peak that is so high even tradingview can't handle it... At least, on my chart. This is how it looks like:
[image: My code/chart but zoomed in]
As you can see at the second of june bitcoin went up so high that it goes out of the screen. This should be fixable since on the actual tradingview page itself it all look good and normal:
[image: TradingView.com]
Also if I zoom out on my chart it look perfectly normal:
[image: My code/chart but zoomed out]
So **what I want** is that my chart scales the same way as it does on tradingview.com.

**This is my code:**

```
// Predifined variables
var chart, priceArea, fetchedData;

// Faster to write log();
const log = console.log;

// Get data.
fetch('./getData.php', {
    method: 'GET'
}).then(response => response.json()).then(function (data) {
    // Set data to a global variable for global usage.
    fetchedData = data;

    // To make sure the chart is initialized and set after this fetch is done. Else I would get a error for setting data that I do not yet have.
    initChartSettings();
});


/**
 * Initializes the chart and its settings.
 */
function initChartSettings() {
    // Create chart canvas
    chart = LightweightCharts.createChart(document.getElementById('Chart'), {width: 1500, height: 700,});

    // Could also be done in the width and height code line but thought it might work for scaling.
    chart.applyOptions({
        timeScale: {
            // Adds hours and minutes to the chart.
            timeVisible: true,
            secondsVisible: false
        }
    });

    // Init price line
    priceArea = chart.addAreaSeries();

    // This array is needed to make the setData work. It expects an array with objects.
    let arrayWithOldData = [];

    // Get each item in the fetchedData array. Since it gives more data then I need I use this for loop to take the time and value. Used to create chart lines.
    for (let i = 0; i < fetchedData.length; i++) {
        let dataElement = fetchedData[i];

        // Object needed for the arrayWithOldData.
        let oldData = {
            // Timestamp / 1000 to make it a workable timestamp for tradingview chart and + 7200 seconds to make sure I get a timestamp of amsterdam (+2:00).
            time: (dataElement[0] / 1000) + 7200,
            value: dataElement[4]
        };

        // Add the data to the array.
        arrayWithOldData.push(oldData);
    }

    log(arrayWithOldData);

    // Set data
    priceArea.setData(arrayWithOldData);

    // PriceLine options
    priceArea.applyOptions({
        topColor: 'rgba(70, 130, 180, 0.5)',
        bottomColor: 'rgba(70, 130, 180, 0.1)',
        lineColor: '#4682B4',
        lineWidth: 2
    });

    startTime = new Date();
    updateLiveChartData();
}
```

**What I have tried:**

I have tried the following in my code: https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/blob/master/docs/customization.md -> price axis -> priceScale() -> autoScale: true and scaleMargins with diffrent top and bottoms. Seems scaleMargins works, but then when I go back in time and make sure I dont see the peak anymore everything is as good as flat :( I also tried to put at the end of the code: chart.timeScale().fitContent(); But this gives the same result as how I have it now but then zoomed out. If I zoom in with timeScale it still looking the same.

Comment: Please make sure that all values you've passed as the data are _numbers_, not strings or something.

Comment: @timocov That can be very good one of the problems. I ignored this problem for a while. And after building it more and more I found out my markers again didn't work. Because I set the price of the priceline series as a string instead of a number. It was not giving me any errors but still fktop the markers and probably also this scaling thing. Since it now all works :)

Comment: I hope we'll fix it soon and will throw an error if you pass something wrong to the library - see https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/issues/315

Comment: It would help ALOT. Especially for people like me, hahaha.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that the issue caused by invalid data format (you've passed strings where numbers are expected). We'll warn in debug mode about invalid types after https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/issues/315.

**EDIT:**
Since milestone 3.2 warnings are shown when debug mode is enabled.

Comment: Spent 3 hours trying to figure out what is going on and the problem was the series time order. Thanks a lot